# Using pandas in django, how to release memory?

Tags: python, django, pandas

In a django project that focuses on data analysis, I use pandas to transform the data to a required format. The process is nice and easy, but the project quickly starts using 1GB of RAM.

I know that Python doesn't really free up memory in this case (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39377643/2115409) and that pandas might have an issue (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2659).

How do I use pandas in a django project without exploding memory?

Comment: How looks your setup? Venv? Docker? K8s? How do you serve app? Webserver? Http server? Runserver? Do you use celery? Maybe you should use celery for resource consuming tasks?

Comment: uWSGI on a shared server

Comment: could you tell me how many processes and threads are used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you can do to have less memory consumption in your Django project. The link that you shared on [releasing memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39100971/how-do-i-release-memory-used-by-a-pandas-dataframe/39377643#39377643) highlights a few of them. However, since you're also dealing with a web framework, there are a couple of other things that you can do.

- **Read data in smaller chunks**: When you read data, it is immediately loaded into the memory for processing. Avoid loading everything at once.
- **Write data in smaller chunks**: Similar to reading data in chunks, write data in chunks rather than all at once. This would reduce bulk-memory consumption while writing large data frames to disk.
- **Ensure correct data types**: Don't rely on default data types that Pandas assign to your data. For example, your data might easily fit into `int32` or `float32` and pandas might have `int64`/`float64` assigned to them. Be explicit where possible (Remember [Zen of Python](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/))
- **See for code-level optimizations**: specifically avoid making a lot of copies of your dataframe. Do in-place transformations rather than re-creating a dataframe for each operation.
- **Use generators** instead of lists as it does not load all data in memory, but `yield` it once necessary.
- **Avoid doing manipulation in request/response cycle**: Finally, avoid doing pandas manipulation in the request/response cycle of Django requests.
- **Use queues**: Shift the data manipulation to [task queues such as celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/). (You can also separate these queues on managed services from the cloud), or just another EC2 instance, for example. You can use distributed queues to further scale your system and lower memory consumption.
- **Querysets**: Use Django querysets efficiently. [They are lazily loaded](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/queries/#caching-and-querysets). Ensure you can `filter` (read chunk) them depending on your needs.
- **Dataframes up for garbage collection**: Make sure you use `del` when you're done with a dataframe. This would remove the reference to the dataframe. Then you can run [`gc.collect()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.collect) to trigger the garbage collector explicitly to free-up memory.

You may also use [`gc.set_threshold` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.set_threshold) to further tune the garbage collector.

A little example of this might look like this:

```
import gc
import pandas as pd

def service_layer_function():
    # generate dataframe
    # get done with it.
    # explicitly release reference to df
    del df
    # trigger garbage collector
    gc.collect()
```

Comment: Thanks! Any idea about garbage collecting the unused pandas dataframes in django?

Comment: Hi @Private I added some other points including explicitly triggering the garbage collector -- but remember to release reference to dataframe objects before running `gc.collect()`. Let me know if you've any other questions.